# Where is renameat2 on Catalina?

Tags: library, macos, command-line

https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/2/renameat/

I see osx has renameat2 as shown here. But I don't find it on Catalina. Could anybody where I can find the manpage of renameat2?

EDIT: `man renameat` gives me something like this. But `renameat2` does not exist on the manpage.

```
RENAME(2)                   BSD System Calls Manual                  RENAME(2)

NAME
     rename, renameat, renamex_np, renameatx_np -- change the name of a file

SYNOPSIS
     #include <stdio.h>

     int
     rename(const char *old, const char *new);

     int
     renameat(int fromfd, const char *from, int tofd, const char *to);

     int
     renamex_np(const char *from, const char *to, unsigned int flags);

     int
     renameatx_np(int fromfd, const char *from, int tofd, const char *to, unsigned int flags);
```

The path of renameat's manpage is here.

```
$ man -w renameat
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/share/man/man2/rename.2
```

Comment: The man page on the linked page starts with „Linux Programmer's Manual“, the text itself clearly refers to Linux. Why do you think this is relevant for macOS?

Comment: It is under the directory of osx. The title says "osx man page".

Comment: Well, looks like somebody made a mistake on that site.

Answer (score 1):

The man page you link to says:

```
renameat2() is Linux-specific.
```

It's never going to be in macOS.

Several other references point to that man page being Linux, not BSD 4.2. It's clearly a mistake.